# Composite keys problems to execute Find()

Tags: entity-framework-5

The number of primary key values passed must match number of primary key values defined on the entity.
Parameter name: keyValues

```
public TEntity Find(int id)
    {

        return _context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
    }
```

[image]

Possible? I know have others ways for that, but I am interesting if is possible to use find on this table.

Answer (score 1):

That`s work... this is not a better way I think, but is there

```
Func<Acesso_LogErro, bool> expressionPerfil = Perf => Perf.idLogErro == id;
        Acesso_LogErro acesso_logerro = acesso_LogErroRepository.Where(expressionPerfil).First();
```